# Could not find gem 'pg (~> 0.17.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm

Just upgraded to:

```
rails', '4.1.7
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
RVM 1.26.0
```

And when I try to

```
$rails s
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 0.17.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

This is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
...
```

I have tried:

```
 $ gem install pg
```

And I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

---

UPDATE 1:

```
rmv list

rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p550 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-rc1 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
```

If I do which ruby I get:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

This means that I am using the system Ruby? Or that RVM was installed under the system folders?

---

Update 2:

I switched from System Ruby. I did:

$rvm use default

```
Using /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4
```

$which ruby:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
```

$ruby -v

```
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

Now if I do

$rails -v

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I am so confused. Does this mean I need to reinstall rails??

Comment: Are you sure you're on rvm ruby rather than the system one? Do a `which ruby` and `ruby -v` in your terminal

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rails s`. Also try to move the `gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1` outside of the `group :production` block

Comment: Just updated my answer, which ruby: /usr/bin/ruby and ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]